# Google App Engine HTTP

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, http, https

With Google App Engine is only HTTP/HTTPS supported? I am wondering since I have a Node.js server which uses raw sockets to send JSON formatted messages between server and client for a mobile app and I want to deploy it onto Google App Engine?

Comment: you are probably looking for GCE not appengine.

Comment: @Zig Mandel Thanks, so if I wanted to host on app engine and benefit from the autoscaling that Google provides I would need to use HTTP?

Comment: GCE also has autoscaling. appengine doesnt natively support javascript server-side. a custom appengine module would be more limited than a simple GCE autoscale farm.

Comment: You can use sockets with the python, java, go, and php sdks. [python docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/)

Comment: Never mind I had other problems with Google Cloud Platform, am now on AWS

Answer (score 0):

**Limitations and restrictions**

Although App Engine supports sockets, there are certain limitations and behaviors you need to be aware of when using sockets:

- Sockets are available only for paid apps.
- You cannot create a listen socket; you can only create outbound sockets. FTP is not supported.
- java.net.URL is still configured to use the URL Fetch API; there is
  currently no way around this.
- InetAddress.isReachable is a no-op.
- Most classes in javax.net.ssl are supported.
- You can only use TCP or UDP; arbitrary protocols are not allowed.
- You cannot bind to specific IP addresses or ports.
- ...

[Overview of Sockets API for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/)